# Using Tabs with Views

Tags: android

I have a little problem using Tabs with Views.
First I just copied the sample code where Tabs are used with activitys:

My LayoutFile looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And this is my Java-code:

```
public class MyActivity extends TabActivity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TabHost tH = getTabHost();

        Indent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AnotherActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        //TextView Test = new TextView(this);
        //Test.setText("test");

        tH.addTab(tH.newTabSpec("t1").setIndicator("Tab1").setContent(intent));
        tH.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

And this works as expected.
But when I uncomment the TextView-lines and call setContent(Test.getId()) instead of setContent(intent), the app crashes.
I also tried to create a textview in the layoutfile, and call setContent(R.id.test),
that also makes it crash.

So this is one problem.

The seccond point is. I do not want to use activitys, because i want to be able to call methods on those classes, which shall represent the Tab-content.
So my original idea is, to derive some classes from view. 1 for each tab, and pass their ids. But therefor the codesample above needs to work first.

greetings Uzaku

Comment: You can't use `setContent(Test.getId()) ` because `getId()` will fail as you haven't given `Test` an id. Try `Test.setId(1234)` then use `setContent(1234)`

Comment: Thank you for that comment, but the problem still persists

Comment: Post the logcat which shows the crash / stack trace.

Comment: The log is quite long, so I uploaded it, here is the link: http://snipt.org/uhfP7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you tried a `TextView` in the layout file but this should work...

Change the `FrameLayout` section as follows...

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:text="TEST" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then in your code do the following...

```
tH.addTab(tH.newTabSpec("t1").setIndicator("Tab1").setContent(R.id.test));
```

Comment: That works, I guess I must have made a mistake, when I tried it that way. Do you have an explanation why it does not work, when creating the TextView in Source?

Comment: Glad it is working for you. No, I'm afraid I can't think why it didn't work with creating the `TextView` with the code. I'm sure there's a good reason though. Perhaps you'd need to get the `FrameLayout` view in code and then add the `TextView` to it before calling `setContent(...)`

Comment: I added a seccond TextView and a seccond Tab. If i display 1 Textview in 1 tab there is no problem, if I try to display the same Textview in both tabs, there are both Textviews over each other, in both tabs.
Why is that? I feel like i missed 1 important tutorial.

Comment: Take a look at this example - it should help. http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html